# python- using splinter to open and login webpage failed, help！！

Tags: python, authentication, splinter

https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=990d5c9e38720f4e832a8009a0fe4cad7dd151f99111dbea0df5e2934f267ec8&language=HK-en&segment=R409&grpcode=g001&view=6&rv=1&paramcode=h006&path=%2Fgeniusbar%2FR409%2Fen_HK&path2=%2Fgeniusbar%2FR409%2Fen_HK

I want to auto login this website,but it's doesn't work not matter browser.fill or `find_by_name` or `find_by_id`

below was the information of input:

```
<input type="email" class="si-text-field" id="appleId" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-labelledby="appleIdFieldLabel" spellcheck="false" autofocus="" placeholder="Apple ID">
<input type="password" id="pwd" aria-required="true" required="required" can-field="password" autocomplete="off" class="si-password si-text-field  " placeholder="Password">
```

but when I use code below,it doesn't work, I don't know any special of the login form,

```
 browser.fill("appleId","***")
    browser.fill("pwd","***")

splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with name "appleId"
```

Comment: I hope these were dummy credentials. Otherwise change them 5 minutes ago.

Comment: <input type="email" class="si-text-field" id="appleId" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-labelledby="appleIdFieldLabel" spellcheck="false" autofocus="" placeholder="Apple ID">
<input type="password" id="pwd" aria-required="true" required="required" can-field="password" autocomplete="off" class="si-password si-text-field  " placeholder="Password">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is inside an `iframe`, *switch* to it before filling the login and password:

```
with browser.get_iframe('aid-auth-widget-iFrame') as iframe:
    browser.find_by_id("appleId").type("your login") 
    browser.find_by_id("pwd").type("your password")
```

Comment: File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\splinter\driver\webdriver\__init__.py", line 414, in fill
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\splinter\element_list.py", line 53, in first
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\splinter\element_list.py", line 44, in __getitem__
splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with name "appleId"

Comment: @caesar318 yeah, you have to use `find_by_id()` - check the updated code in the answer.